# Bootstrap responsive image not working

Tags: image

I am new with bootstrap. I have the following problem with responsive image using bootstrap. My image doesn't seem to scale. I have no idea what might have gone wrong.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div class = "container"> 

        <div class = "col-small-12">

            <div class = "row">

                <a href="***"> <img src="images/web.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"> </a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's responsive image class sets max-width to 100%. This limits its size, but does not force it to stretch to fill parent elements larger than the image itself. You'd have to use the width attribute to force upscaling.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive